# How can I give parameters to a function of a python script through the command-line?

Tags: python, function, command-line, parameters

Currently this is my python script (**TagGen**) which has one function:

```
def SJtag(file,len_tag):

    import csv
    reader = csv.reader(open(file), dialect='excel-tab' )
    for row in reader:
        qstarts = row[1].split(",")[1:-1] 
        n = len_tag/2
        for i in qstarts:  
            name = row[0]

            start = int(i)-n
            if start<0:
                start = 0      

            end = int(i)+n
            if end>len(row[2]):
                end=len(row[2])

            tag = row[2][start:end]    
            print name, i, tag, len(tag)

SJtag("QstartRefseqhg19.head",80)
```

I want to give the **file** and **len_tag** parameters of the **SJtag** function using bash comand line, something like this:

```
python ./TagGen QstartRefseqhg19.head 80
```

**How can I do this, or some thing similar?**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.argv` is the arguments list, with the first element being the script name. It's a list of strings, so if any of the parameters are numbers, you'll have to convert them using `int()` or `float()`.

So, if you called  a script like so:

```
$ python myscript.py 1 foo bar baz
```

`sys.argv` would be this:

```
["myscript.py", "1", "foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

In your case, you could make your script this:

```
import sys
import csv

def SJtag(file,len_tag):
    reader = csv.reader(open(file), dialect='excel-tab' )
    for row in reader:
        qstarts = row[1].split(",")[1:-1] 
        n = len_tag/2
        for i in qstarts:  
            name = row[0]

            start = int(i)-n
            if start<0:
                start = 0      

            end = int(i)+n
            if end>len(row[2]):
                end=len(row[2])

            tag = row[2][start:end]    
            print name, i, tag, len(tag)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SJtag(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [argparse module](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) for that.

From the docs,

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
           help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
           const=sum, default=max,
           help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print args.accumulate(args.integers)
```

If you are using a version of python earlier than 2.7, you should use the [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) module, to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: That's probably a bit of overkill in this case. argparse really only comes in handy when you want to take command line switches, etc, but in a simple case like this, argv works.

Comment: Rafe, If all you need is a couple of command line parameters, may be. But not too far when you complicate that too much and are much better to use an inbuilt library function. :)

Comment: oh, absolutely. It's also worth noting that argparse is 2.7 and up.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend `argparse` and a nice wrapper for it called [`plac`](http://micheles.googlecode.com/hg/plac/doc/plac.html). In your case all you'd need to do is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import plac; plac.call(SJtag)
```

...and `plac`will handle everything, as *it is able to figure out the command-line arguments to use from the signature of your function*. Very cool, check out the docs for more (it can do a lot more).

Answer (score 0):

Just refer to this.

http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/NBN/python_intro/command_line.html