# How to dynamically store values from .json file and compare them with user input in python?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, json

I have .json file like this:

```
[
{
    "name": {
        "common": "Aruba",
        "official": "Aruba",
        "native": {
            "nld": {
                "official": "Aruba",
                "common": "Aruba"
            },
            "pap": {
                "official": "Aruba",
                "common": "Aruba"
            }
        }
    },
    "tld": [
        ".aw"
    ],
    "cca2": "AW",
    "ccn3": "533",
    "cca3": "ABW",
    "cioc": "ARU",
    "independent": false,
    "status": "officially-assigned",
    "unMember": false,
    "currencies": {
        "AWG": {
            "name": "Aruban florin",
            "symbol": "\u0192"
        }
    },
    "idd": {
        "root": "+2",
        "suffixes": [
            "97"
        ]
    },
    "capital": [
        "Oranjestad"
    ],
    "altSpellings": [
        "AW"
    ],
    "region": "Americas",
    "subregion": "Caribbean",
    "languages": {
        "nld": "Dutch",
        "pap": "Papiamento"
    },
    "translations": {
        "ces": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "deu": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "est": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "fin": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "fra": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "hrv": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "hun": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "ita": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "jpn": {
            "official": "\u30a2\u30eb\u30d0",
            "common": "\u30a2\u30eb\u30d0"
        },
        "kor": {
            "official": "\uc544\ub8e8\ubc14",
            "common": "\uc544\ub8e8\ubc14"
        },
        "nld": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "per": {
            "official": "\u0622\u0631\u0648\u0628\u0627",
            "common": "\u0622\u0631\u0648\u0628\u0627"
        },
        "pol": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "por": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "rus": {
            "official": "\u0410\u0440\u0443\u0431\u0430",
            "common": "\u0410\u0440\u0443\u0431\u0430"
        },
        "slk": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "spa": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "swe": {
            "official": "Aruba",
            "common": "Aruba"
        },
        "urd": {
            "official": "\u0627\u0631\u0648\u0628\u0627",
            "common": "\u0627\u0631\u0648\u0628\u0627"
        },
        "zho": {
            "official": "\u963f\u9c81\u5df4",
            "common": "\u963f\u9c81\u5df4"
        }
    }
},
    
{
    "name": {
        "common": "Afghanistan",
        "official": "Islamic Republic of Afghanistan",
        "native": {
            "prs": {
                "official": "\u062c\u0645\u0647\u0648\u0631\u06cc \u0627\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645\u06cc \u0627\u0641\u063a\u0627\u0646\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646",
                "common": "\u0627\u0641\u063a\u0627\u0646\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646"
            },
            "pus": {
                "official": "\u062f \u0627\u0641\u063a\u0627\u0646\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645\u064a \u062c\u0645\u0647\u0648\u0631\u06cc\u062a",
                "common": "\u0627\u0641\u063a\u0627\u0646\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646"
            },
            "tuk": {
                "official": "Owganystan Yslam Respublikasy",
                "common": "Owganystan"
            }
        }
    },
    "tld": [
        ".af"
    ],
    "cca2": "AF",
    "ccn3": "004",
    "cca3": "AFG",
    "cioc": "AFG",
    "independent": true,
    "status": "officially-assigned",
    "unMember": true,
    "currencies": {
        "AFN": {
            "name": "Afghan afghani",
            "symbol": "\u060b"
        }
    },
    "idd": {
        "root": "+9",
        "suffixes": [
            "3"
        ]
    },
    "capital": [
        "Kabul"
    ],
    "altSpellings": [
        "AF",
        "Af\u0121\u0101nist\u0101n"
    ],
    "region": "Asia",
    "subregion": "Southern Asia",
    "languages": {
        "prs": "Dari",
        "pus": "Pashto",
        "tuk": "Turkmen"
    },
    "translations": {
        "ces": {
            "official": "Afgh\u00e1nsk\u00e1 isl\u00e1msk\u00e1 republika",
            "common": "Afgh\u00e1nist\u00e1n"
        },
        "cym": {
            "official": "Gweriniaeth Islamaidd Affganistan",
            "common": "Affganistan"
        },
        "deu": {
            "official": "Islamische Republik Afghanistan",
            "common": "Afghanistan"
        },
        "est": {
            "official": "Afganistani Islamivabariik",
            "common": "Afganistan"
        },
        "fin": {
            "official": "Afganistanin islamilainen tasavalta",
            "common": "Afganistan"
        },
        "fra": {
            "official": "R\u00e9publique islamique d'Afghanistan",
            "common": "Afghanistan"
        },
        "hrv": {
            "official": "Islamska Republika Afganistan",
            "common": "Afganistan"
        },
        "hun": {
            "official": "Afganiszt\u00e1ni Iszl\u00e1m K\u00f6zt\u00e1rsas\u00e1g",
            "common": "Afganiszt\u00e1n"
        },
        "ita": {
            "official": "Repubblica islamica dell'Afghanistan",
            "common": "Afghanistan"
        },
        "jpn": {
            "official": "\u30a2\u30d5\u30ac\u30cb\u30b9\u30bf\u30f3\u00b7\u30a4\u30b9\u30e9\u30e0\u5171\u548c\u56fd",
            "common": "\u30a2\u30d5\u30ac\u30cb\u30b9\u30bf\u30f3"
        },
        "kor": {
            "official": "\uc544\ud504\uac00\ub2c8\uc2a4\ud0c4 \uc774\uc2ac\ub78c \uacf5\ud654\uad6d",
            "common": "\uc544\ud504\uac00\ub2c8\uc2a4\ud0c4"
        },
        "nld": {
            "official": "Islamitische Republiek Afghanistan",
            "common": "Afghanistan"
        },
        "per": {
            "official": "\u062c\u0645\u0647\u0648\u0631\u06cc \u0627\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645\u06cc \u0627\u0641\u063a\u0627\u0646\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646",
            "common": "\u0627\u0641\u063a\u0627\u0646\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646"
        },
        "pol": {
            "official": "Islamska Republika Afganistanu",
            "common": "Afganistan"
        },
        "por": {
            "official": "Rep\u00fablica Isl\u00e2mica do Afeganist\u00e3o",
            "common": "Afeganist\u00e3o"
        },
        "rus": {
            "official": "\u0418\u0441\u043b\u0430\u043c\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f \u0420\u0435\u0441\u043f\u0443\u0431\u043b\u0438\u043a\u0430 \u0410\u0444\u0433\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0430\u043d",
            "common": "\u0410\u0444\u0433\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0430\u043d"
        },
        "slk": {
            "official": "Afg\u00e1nsky islamsk\u00fd \u0161t\u00e1t",
            "common": "Afganistan"
        },
        "spa": {
            "official": "Rep\u00fablica Isl\u00e1mica de Afganist\u00e1n",
            "common": "Afganist\u00e1n"
        },
        "swe": {
            "official": "Islamiska republiken Afghanistan",
            "common": "Afghanistan"
        },
        "urd": {
            "official": "\u0627\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645\u06cc \u062c\u0645\u06c1\u0648\u0631\u06cc\u06c1 \u0627\u0641\u063a\u0627\u0646\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646",
            "common": "\u0627\u0641\u063a\u0627\u0646\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646"
        },
        "zho": {
            "official": "\u963f\u5bcc\u6c57\u4f0a\u65af\u5170\u5171\u548c\u56fd",
            "common": "\u963f\u5bcc\u6c57"
        }
    },
    "latlng": [
        33,
        65
    ],
    "landlocked": true,
    "borders": [
        "IRN",
        "PAK",
        "TKM",
        "UZB",
        "TJK",
        "CHN"
    ],
    "area": 652230,
    "flag": "\ud83c\udde6\ud83c\uddeb"
    
}]
```

I access it through Javascipt code `const data = require('./countries.json');`. What I need from this .json file is `translation keys`, for example `ces`, `deu`, etc. I need to retrieve them dynamically and store in the array called `keys`. After that, depending on user's input, if input is equal to one of the `keys` from an array it should print official name of all countries using this key.
In my Javascript code I use following methods to do so:

```
const data = require('./countries.json');
const keys = [];
data.forEach((element) => {
Object.keys(element.translations).forEach((item) => {
keys.push(item);
}) ;
});

/**
*Removes all duplicate translation keys
*@param {1} keys of translation keys
*@return {unique} a unique array of translation keys
*/
function removeDuplicates (keys) { 
const unique = [];
      keys.forEach((element) => {
if (!unique.includes(element)) {
  unique.push(element);
}
});
return unique;
}
const enteredKey = process.argv.slice(2);
console.log('Key is : ', enteredKey);

if (enteredKey.length < 2 && enteredKey !== null && removeDuplicates(keys).includes(enteredKey[0])) {
try {
for (const {translations} of data) {
  const key = translations[enteredKey]?.official;
  if (key) {
    console.log(key);
  }
 }
}
```

Please note that I am using `const key = translations[enteredKey]?.official;` because there are a lot of countries and few of them do not have some keys, like `cym` key is appear in only half of the countries. Without `[enteredKey]?.official` program will crush because it won't be able to find this key and define it.

Now I need to the same, but with `python3`. I have tried :

```
f = open('./countries.json')
translationKeys = json.load(f)
keys = []
for i in translationKeys[0]["translations"]:
  keys.append(i)
print(keys)
f.close()
```

but the output was really messy:

```
['ces']
['ces', 'deu']
['ces', 'deu', 'est']
['ces', 'deu', 'est', 'fin']
```

Since I am not familiar with python at all, I am curious how to retrieve and store these keys the same way I did that in Javascript and print value of these keys depend on user's input.
If user enters `deu`, program should print every country's official name with `deu` as a parameter. Kinda like this:
[image]

I will leave a github link for those who wish to see entire project to get more context if needed: https://github.com/TheRadioDept/technical-question

Comment: Please update the indentation of your python code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: Ok, so just unindent the 'print()' statement.

Comment: So it should now just print a list of all the keys once?

Comment: @quamrana yes. I have added screenshot of how it works on JS. It should do the same.

Comment: @quamrana do you happen to know solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after I managed to correct the `json` you posted, I came up with this code which should get you going.

It reads the `json` from `countries.json` and samples it for the `"official"` country name, plus all the translations into other languages:

```py
import json

with open('countries.json') as f:
    countries = json.load(f)

official_keys = {}
for c in countries:
    official_keys[c['name']['official']] = c['translations']

cc = input('Type country code: ')
for official, keys  in official_keys.items():
    if cc in keys:
        print(official, '=>', keys[cc]["official"])
```

Typical session:

```
Type country code: deu
Aruba => Aruba
Islamic Republic of Afghanistan => Islamische Republik Afghanistan
```

Comment: I have one question. Is it possible to use cc not as an input, but as terminal parameter. LIke `python3 main.py deu` would print all the countries? I know it is kinda unrelated to the main question, but still will be happy if you can answer.

Comment: That's a different question, but it has been asked and answered many times here, so you just need to search for it. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959172/how-can-i-give-parameters-to-a-function-of-a-python-script-through-the-command-l) seems similar to what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you keep the country codes in a dict format. This way you can easily access the underlying data. Note, this only works if all countries have a unique country code. With opening a file you should use the with statement so python closes the file automatically and not damage data.

```
    with open('./countries.json','r') as f:
        translationKeys = json.load(f)[0]["translations"]
```

now you can try to match user input

```
    inp = input('Please provide a country key:')
    if inp in translationKeys.keys():
        print(translationKeys[inp]["official"])
    else:
        print('This country code was not found')
```

in case you want to list them all you can also loop through the json file. dict.get() will return the corresponding key if it is found, otherwise None.

```
    inp = input()
    for element in translationKeys:
        if element == inp:
            print(translationKeys[inp]['official'])
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped. But there is a problem: It only prints the first country, and I have more than 40 in this .json file. Mostly all of them the same `key`, like `edu`. I tried your code with `input = edu` and it returned translation only for first element ignoring other countries.

Comment: Yes that is because in python a dictionary can only have unique keys, otherwise it will overwrite. In this case you could try to loop through all of the elements and print if it matches the input.

Comment: I added screenshot of working program in JS. Is it possible to make it work like this in python?

Comment: `
with open('./countries.json','r') as f:
                translationKeys = json.load(f)[0]["translations"]

        inp = input('Please provide a country key:')
        for element in translationKeys:
            country = element.get(inp)
            if country != None:
                print(country.get('official'))
`
dict.get() will return None if the key is not found. Therefore it will only print if the country exists

Comment: I tried and it returned an error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'`